# Ansible / VMWARE - Retrieve network interface labels and start them according to the information for each VM

Tags: ansible, vmware-vcenter, jquery

**Context**

I'd like to retrieve the network interface labels for each VM, which I define directly in a variable array, and connect them. Knowing that the network interfaces already exist on each VMs.

I already have a script for this and it's work but I'd like it to be more adaptive.

The first part : "Get network interfaces label" is hard for me to find out how to list interfaces and make vmware_guest_network take all of them for each VMs.

**Environnement**

- ESXI / vCenter version : 7.0 U3
- Ansible_core version : 2.16.1
- Ansible version : 9.1.0
- VM OS : RedHat 8.7

**Which script**

vars:

```
  array:
    - name: "vm_1"
      folder: "/datacenter/vm/"
      storage: "Storage_1"
      cluster: "{{ cluster3 }}"
    - name: "vm_2"
      folder: "/datacenter/vm/"
      storage: "Storage_1"
      cluster: "{{ cluster2 }}"
    - name: "vm_3"
      folder: "/datacenter/vm/"
      storage: "Storage_5"
      cluster: "{{ cluster3 }}"
```

---

```
- name: Configure Network interfaces
  vmware_guest_network:

    hostname: "{{ ip_vcenter }}"
    username: "{{ username_vcenter }}"
    password: "{{ password_vcenter }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    validate_certs: no

    name: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    label: "{{ item.1 }}"
    state: present
  with_nested:
    - "{{ array }}"
    - [ "Network adapter 1", "Network adapter 2", "Network adapter 3" ]
```

**What tasks i want to do**

- Get all informations of VMs indicated on array.name variable
- List all Network adapter of each VMs and format it to list var
- Connect all Network adapter according to the first task result

**What i have tried**

I have tried multiple format with :

Get all informations of VMs indicated on array.name variable

```
- name: Configure Network interfaces
  vmware_guest_network:
    
    hostname: "{{ ip_vcenter }}"
    username: "{{ username_vcenter }}"
    password: "{{ password_vcenter }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    validate_certs: no
    
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ array }}"
  register: vm_info
```

List all Network adapter of each VMs and format it to list var

set_facts with jquery request based on vm_info return and array variable but i got completely lost on what I wanted to write...

**Question**

What technique would you have used ?